# Expressing math inequality proof with correct notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that

$$|y| \ge |y_0| - |y-y_0|$$

I am not able to prove this properly.  I can only prove it using sentences.  I was recently told that this is not a proper math proof by my professor and that he would not accept it until I corrected it.  I am unsure as to what I have done wrong, as he will not tell me.  How can I make this proof proper?

This is my "proof."

**Case 1**
$y > y_0$

$$|y| + |y - y_0| \ge |y_0|$$

True, since $|y - y_0| > 0$

**Case 2**
$y=y_0$

$$|y| \ge |y_0| - |y - y_0|$$
$$|y| \ge |y| - |y-y|$$
$$|y| = |y|$$
$$y = y$$

True

**Case 3**
$y < y_0$

Since $|y-y_0|$ is the difference between $y$ and $y_0$ and $y < y_0$ 
then $$y + |y-y_0|=y_0$$

True

EDIT: Just thought I'd add in that $y$ and $y_0$ are not imaginary numbers.  They must be between $[-\infty, +\infty]$

Comment: In **Case 1**, why does $|y - y_0| > 0$ imply that $|y| + |y - y_0| \geq |y_0|$?

Comment: If we substitute $n = |y-y_0|$ then we have $|y| + n \ge |y_0|$.  By the definition of an absolute value function $n > 0$ and since $y > y_0$ this means that $y$ has to be larger than $y_0$

Comment: From $y>y_0$ you cannot conclude $|y| > |y_0|$.  Consider $y=5$ and $y_0 = -8$.

Comment: Proof by cases is OK (but can be less "nice"). However, as pointed ouut by Adriano, Case 1 is not proved. Case 2 is handled in a poor way, one should not go from what one wants to a true thing. Anyway, Case 2 is trivial. If $y=y_0$ then $|y|+|y-y_0|=|y|=|y_0|$.

Comment: Your proof has some problems, but if your professor says that the main problem is the presence of "sentences" rather than solely using formulas, I would disagree *strongly*.  The style of your proof is just fine. The *logic* of your proof, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

As pointed out in the comments your first step isn't quite true. For instance,
$$
-2 > -3 \text{ but } |-2| = 2 < 3 = |-3|
$$
so that one cannot directly conclude
$$
y > y_0 \implies |y| + |y - y_0| \ge |y_0|
$$

**Hint:**
$$
| a + b | \le |a| + |b| \; \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}
$$

**Remark:**

The style you use in cases 2 and 3 are not really *proofs* in the traditional sense. Logically, we should start with some fact we know to be true and then conclude the statement we want to find, as opposed to the opposite (showing, in a certain situation the statement we want to find implies some sort of true statement). For example I can claim
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \le 5 \implies a_n \le 5 \; \forall n
$$
and then assume the statement to be true and say that
$$
a_n \le 5 \forall n
$$
which then indeed implies
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \le 5
$$
which is the initial condition, so the theorem must be true. But this theorem in fact is not true (why?).